# How to relate values of a single attribute in database

Tags: mysql, database, attributes, translation, relationship

I am confused about how to make relationship among values of a single attribute in a MYSQL database for e.g. I have two tables in database named "Language" and "Dictionary" so in Entity "Language" there are two attributes 1st is "language_id" and the other is "Name" in language_id an id for the language name is stored and in attribute "Name" language name is stored for e.g. "language_id = 201" "Name = English" and in Entity "Dictionary" there are three attributes 1st is "id" which is the primary key 2nd is "Word" where words are stored according to the name of the language and 3rd is "language_id" which is being used as a foreign key to implement one to many relation. Now the Confusion is that if I store two different languages such as English and Urdu with different language_id's words get successfully stored in attribute "Word" with their respective foreign keys but how can i relate words of two different languages which have same meaning in order to achieve translation. All the replies are worth appreciation. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought is to add an extra column to Dictionary which references a primary word. The two tables might look like this:

```
Language
--------
language_id
name

Dictionary
----------
id
word
language_id
primary_id
```

If the primary word is in English, it would have a primary_id of null. Each successive language added would then set primary_id to the id of the English word.

```
language_id | name
-----------   ----
201         | English
202         | Spanish

id | word    | language_id | primary_id
--   ----      -----------   ----------
1  | hello   | 201         | null
2  | goodbye | 201         | null
3  | hola    | 202         | 1
4  | adios   | 202         | 2
```

Comment: Thanks A-Lot for the Help.